# verify type size in C static library

Tags: c, linker

my app (Android/iOS) needs to link its C code with a 3rd party prebuilt static library (.a).
the library's headers define a struct like so:

```
struct s_st {
    # ifdef SSS_64_BIT
    int64_t mmm;
    # else
    int32_t mmm;
    # endif
};
```

SSS_64_BIT is defined by the Configure script prior to compilation.
my code uses s_st in its code, and i want to make sure that future developers won't change the library's configuration without changing the app or vice versa, resulting in a size mismatch. so, a verification on the size inside the library is required.

there are methods in the library that receive an s_st typed parameter, but calling them with a different sized struct did not seem to cause any linker issues as i'd hoped. also, as a side note, there's no global variable of this type.

is there a way to get the linker to fail somehow if my app's s_st size is different than the library's? if there's a way to check the size of s_st through some external tool such as Objdump, in a way that can be easily scripted, that could also work.

Comment: `SSS_64_BIT` is it macro, type or object?

Comment: if you know autoconf, you can use `AC_CHECK_SIZEOF` in configure.ac file.

Comment: @AliTavakol sounds like an option if i am compiling the library myself. but i'm looking for a general solution for 3rd party libraries that are prebuilt. i edited the question accordingly. thanks.